# AS3 am i using array.slice() currently?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I want to remove a value from a array, at a set index.

this is the while loop i have

```
while (i < objects.length)
{
    var index:int = get_index(objects[i]);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        Quadtree_list[index].insert(objects[i]);
        objects.slice(i, 1);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

sooner or later i cannot get out the loop, so it crashes

but if i replace objects.slice with object.pop, it works (but its not removing the right index)

quick note `objects.slice(i, 1)` is not reducing the length of the array but `objects.pop()` is, how do i make .slice() reduce the size of the array?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.slice(x,y)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#slice%28%29) returns an Array containing the elements from index x to index y.

I believe what you're after is [`Array.splice(startIndex, deleteCount)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29), this is a multi-purpose function. In your code `objects.splice(i, 1);`

1. Starting from index (startIndex)
2. Remove elements up to deleteCount (1)
3. return an Array containing removed elements

Comment: Ah you're so fast :) Great answer though!

Comment: YES, thank you, i got them missed up lol. I knew i was being stupid. Thx again.